# Ray of enfeeblement wording

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am running into a semantics issue. *Ray of enfeeblement* states:

> A coruscating ray springs from your hand. You must succeed on a ranged touch attack to strike a target. The subject takes a penalty to Strength equal to **1d6+1 per two caster levels** **(maximum 1d6+5).** The subject’s Strength score cannot drop below 1.

When I read this originally I thought 1d6+1 per 2 caster levels would be 5d6+5 at level 10. But it seems like some wording is missing that has the level apply only to the +1 and not to the die roll.

For instance *cure light wounds* specifically states

> When laying your hand upon a living creature, you channel positive energy that cures 1**d8 points of damage +1 point per caster level** (maximum +5).

Is *ray of enfeeblement* just worded poorly?

Comment: It's worded the exact same and has an example though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s ambiguous wording but they pretty consistently use the “per” wording to refer to only the closest thing, rather than the entire expression. That is, given \$\DeclareMathOperator{\per}{per}x + y \per z\$, you have \$x + \left(y \per z\right)\$, not \$\left(x + y\right) \per z\$. (This is arguably consistent with the order of operations in mathematics, if we treat “per” as indicating division—if we have \$x + y / z\$ we expect the division to be performed before the addition.)

So both *ray of enfeeblement* and *cure light wounds* work the same way: they scale the added number to a max of +5, and the die does not change. At 5th level, *cure light wounds* maxes out at 1d8+5, and at 10th, *ray of enfeeblement* maxes out at 1d6+5. The entry for the maximum on *ray of enfeeblement* is slightly clearer, and would probably be my preference for clarifying; I don’t know why they gave the maximum entry on *cure light wounds* short shrift.

I cannot actually think of any examples of spells that scale in both dice and flat numbers—you have things like *fireball* that deal 1d6 damage per level, but there is no bonus there.

Comment: out of curiosity wouldn't magic missile technically scale both? 1d4+1 points of force dmg per missile, 5 missiles at 9th level for a technical 5d4+5

Comment: @CriticalCrafting Right, I meant that a spell somehow tries to have *per* “directly” apply to some expression. Things like *magic missile*, where *per* applies not to a damage expression directly, but to something that has its own inner damage expression, aren’t terribly uncommon.